# Find Top Combinations with Multiple Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns where Column A is "item name", Column B is "revenue to gain from sales", and Column C is "purchase price". I am looking to compare the items column to show the different combinations of how I can achieve the highest "revenue to gain from sales" while staying within a budget of total "purchase price".

As an example, I have a list of grocery store items where each item has its own revenue to gain and a purchase price. How can I mix and match different items to purchase while giving me the best combination to achieve highest revenue?

I have heard that Solver may be able to assist with this type of thing?

[image: Example of spreadsheet setup]

Answer (score 1):

Solver would do a good with this for you. The first thing I did was add a few more columns for clarity. The first is Revenue - B x D, Cost D x E Profit it D-E. I added totals to this columns then asked solver to maximize the total profit by changing the quantity mix.

I've also added a few rules to solver to make this work. 
$D$4:$D$11 = integer you want whole numbers 
$D$4:$D$11 >= 0 otherwise it will return negative numbers.

I change your pricing in the screen cap otherwise your solution is buy only Bananas.
[image]